# How is promo code used for iOS app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

What's a promo code used for? Why does one need it? Why not just release the app and if people want to download it, they do. What's the point of promo code if your app is already ready for release anyways?

For example if you want to give your app to iOS review sites is it better to give them a promo code before you put app in App Store or just let them download the app for review from App store?

Comment: If it is a paid app, most reviewers will not download it. That's why you would provide them a promo code, to give them a free copy.

Comment: What if it's a free to download app?

Comment: Then they may download it with out a code. But if you give them a code, you can track if the have downloaded it or not.

The code is a promo code, for PROMOTION. Use it to try and get influential people (bloggers, reviewers...) to try your app.

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents them quite extensively. Feel free to ask a more specific follow on question once you have read the documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html

One awesome advantage of them is that you can seed pre-release versions of an app by controlling the use of codes and release dates once specific versions of your app have been approved for sale.